# Binding command in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a MenuFlyout in my App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <MenuFlyout x:Key="LessonFlyout">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit"/>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete"/>
    </MenuFlyout>
</Application.Resources>
```

And I wanted to give MenuFlyoutItem click event but the compiler says I can't do this. But I need a click event so I searched and found out that I can bind command to MenuFlyoutItem.

My MenuFlyout will be attached to a different objects in different pages. For example:

```
    StackPanel thisSender = sender as StackPanel;
    FlyoutBase.SetAttachedFlyout(thisSender, Application.Current.Resources["LessonFlyout"] as MenuFlyout);
    FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(thisSender);
```

So I need when I click to MenuFlyoutItem it will call my function. So how do I do this?

Also quick question, in the official Microsoft Page about MenuFlyout there's said that there is an Icon attribute to MenuFlyoutItem but in my case I don't have it and VS says that there's an error.

```
The member "Icon" is not recognized or is not accessible.   
The property 'Icon' was not found in type 'MenuFlyoutItem'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For different objects in different pages, the `MenuFlyoutItem` and its `Command` would be different, so usually, we won't put the `MenuFlyout` in `Application.Resources`. But if you can make sure the `MenuFlyoutItem`s used in different `Page`s are the same, then the following might be a solution for you.

Firstly, in *App.xaml*, set `Binding` for `Command`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <MenuFlyout x:Key="LessonFlyout">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit" Command="{Binding EditCommand}" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
    </MenuFlyout>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then implement [I​Command Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ICommand) like the [*RelayCommand.cs*](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/blob/master/XamlControlsGallery/Common/RelayCommand.cs) in official sample.

After this, we need to implement `EditCommand` and `DeleteCommand` in view model so that the binding can work. For example:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ICommand EditCommand { get; set; }

    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        EditCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            //TODO
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("EditCommand");
        });
        DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            //TODO
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DeleteCommand");
        });
    }
}
```

And then attach the `MenuFlyout` like:

```
StackPanel thisSender = sender as StackPanel;
thisSender.DataContext = new ViewModel();
FlyoutBase.SetAttachedFlyout(thisSender, Application.Current.Resources["LessonFlyout"] as MenuFlyout);
FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(thisSender);
```

The `ViewModel` used here is just for example, usually you should have a view model for your page and if so there is no need to set `DataContext` when attaching the `MenuFlyout`. Setting `EditCommand` and `DeleteCommand` in your page's view model should be enough to work.

---

For the following error:

> The member "Icon" is not recognized or is not accessible.
>   The property 'Icon' was not found in type 'MenuFlyoutItem'.

This is because your project is targeting a version earlier than **Build 15063**. In [Icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyoutitem#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_MenuFlyoutItem_Icon) property, we can find **Additional features and requirements** that indicates this property is introduced in **Windows 10 Creators Update (v10.0.15063.0)**. So to use this property, please make sure you are targeting Build 15063 or later.