# Repeat a set of controls in UWP using button clicks dynamically and programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to add set of controls dynamically every time the user clicks **add** button and remove when they click the **delete** button.
[Controls to be repeated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGC4q.png)

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0iL4.png)

[After clicking **Add Item**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjH82.png)

The XAML Code

```
<StackPanel Name="itemStack" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
    <AutoSuggestBox Name="itemCategory"
                PlaceholderText="Ring"
                Header="Item Category" 
                Grid.Row="3" 
                Grid.Column="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                QueryIcon="List"
                Margin="10,10,10,0"
                />
    <AutoSuggestBox Name="itemDescription" 
                PlaceholderText="3 White Stone Ring" 
                Header="Description of the Jewels"                          
                Grid.Row="3" 
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                QueryIcon="List"
                Margin="10,10,10,0"
                />
    <TextBox Name="qty" 
        Text="1" 
        Header="Quantity"
        Grid.Row="3" 
        Grid.Column="4"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Margin="10,10,10,0"
        />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="5">
        <AppBarButton Name="addItem_button"
                    Icon="Add"
                    Label="Add item"                                    
                    LabelPosition="Default"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Click="addItem_button_Click"
                    />
        <AppBarButton Name="deleteItem_button"
                    Icon="Cancel"
                    Label="Del item"
                    LabelPosition="Default"      
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

I want to repeat the whole stack panel including the appbar buttons.

Comment: Where do you want to repeat it? In a repeating control as Listview or you want to add it as child of another control?

Comment: I want to repeat it in the immediate next grid row. I've added a couple of images/screenshots for better clarity

Comment: Have a look at DataTemplates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MVVM (model-view-view model) data-binding would with a `ListView` would be ideal for this scenario.

What you will need to do is to create a `ListView` which will contain the `StackPanel` as its `ItemTemplate`. Then you will need a `ViewModel` class, that will be data-bound to the controls in `TwoWay` manner, which will ensure that the values selected in the controls will be projected on the `ViewModel` classes. Finally, to create the buttons functionality, you will need to bind the actions to the `Command` property.

As this is a lot to take on at first, I recommend you to check out some simple tutorials on data binding in UWP first:

- [Basics on Data Binding](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/windows10_development/windows10_development_data_binding.htm)
- [Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900455/binding-command-in-uwp)
- [`x:Bind` sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlBind)
- [Minimal MVVM app](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/)

Comment: I will look into this. Thank you for directing me.

Comment: Hope it helps :-) . I know that this solution is a tad more complex, but MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) pattern is the recommended way to develop UWP apps and it will help you write a more maintainable code in the long run, so it is worth learning to do it from the start :-) .

Comment: I have added one more link with a tutorial for a simple MVVM app

Answer (score 0):

As @Martin said in his answer, the common way of acheiving what you want is using a Listview with ItemTemplate.

If you want to insert it in a grid row, that means you will have to a lot work programatically : create the controls, update the grid rows and insert controls. You must also monitor when you remove controls to update the grid.

If you want to go that way, wrap your xaml in a custom control so you can reuse it. Then manipulate your grid's `Children` property in code-behind... You'll use the Grid attached property `Grid.SetRow` to assign the row to your control.

As you can see, it's a lot